# Get current value that a global variable is pointing to

Tags: ruby

I have some code written like this

```
$var1 = 2
$var2 = 4
...

keywords = {"one" => $var1, "two" => $var2, ...}
```

The problem is that I want to get the value stored in that variable when I hash into `keywords`, but ruby doesn't seem to be re-evaluating the variables when I need them. So if `$var1` was changed during execution, `keywords["one"]` still returns the original value of `2`

How can I change the hash so that I will first determine which variable I need to access, and then go and grab its value?

There are quite a number of global variables (they didn't use array?), and I don't want to have redundant case/when or if/elsif blocks.

EDIT: A more precise question would be

"How do I retrieve the value that a variable is currently pointing to?"

Comment: It would make it much easier to just edit the hash values. Why are the extra variables necessary?

Comment: I don't have control over the variables. It's bad code that I have to work with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general this seems like a bad idea. Instead of updating $var1 just update the hash and always access $var1 through keywords["one"]

You could use eval, but it's not a good solution:

```
$var1 = 2
$var2 = 4
...
keywords = {"one" => "$var1", "two" => "$var2", ...}
$var1 = 6
var1 = eval(keywords["one"])  # -> 6
```

Update: Note that the eval will take any code you pass in and execute it. You need to be very careful that the thing you're evaling is of the form you expect. It can be a big security risk.

Comment: I'd love to update the hash instead, but it's the contents that $var1 points to that's getting updated and I'm getting the values through that variable. Though, is there still risk of malicious strings being passed into that eval call if I do things that way?

Comment: @Keikoku You should accept this answer (after you have waited long enough to feel confident that this is the best answer you will get). You've been warned and understand that this is a gross hack, but Ruby (intentionally) provides no other mechanism to achieve what you want except for `eval`.

Answer (score 1):

Variables do not *contain* values, they *reference* them. When you write:

```
foo = 2
bar = [foo]
foo = 4
```

…it does not cause `bar` to be `[4]`. What ~happens is:

1. Create a value `2` in memory and set the variable `foo` to reference it.
2. Create a new array whose first slot references the value referenced by `foo` (i.e. `2`), and set the variable `bar` to reference that array.
3. Create a value `4` in memory and change the variable `foo` to reference it instead.

Some object types that are mutable. For example, you can change the actual contents of a String or an Array to be different. In this case, all references to that value reflect the change:

```
foo = "hello"
bar = [foo]
foo[0] = "j"
p bar        #=> ["jello"]
```

Numbers are not mutable, however. If you want to have a 'handle' to a number than you can change and have all other references to that number change, you will need to wrap the number in a mutable data type. For example:

```
$var1 = [2]
keywords = { "one"=>$var1 }
p keywords["one"][0] #=> 2
$var1[0] = 4
p keywords["one"][0] #=> 4
```

Now, if your values are *not* numbers, but are strings (as "keywords" implies) then you can mutate and wholly replace those:

```
$var1 = "foo"
keywords = { "one"=>$var1 }
$var1.replace( "bar" )
p keywords["one"]           #=> "bar"
```

The key is that **you must be calling a method on the object itself** (and that method must change the object itself, not return a new object); you cannot make this work using variable assignment. For example, see [`String#replace`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-replace).

Comment: @mliebelt It wasn't then, but it is now. :)

Comment: Yes, some of the values are mutable types. Though, now I'm not sure why I always get the original values rather than the updated values based on what you've written. It might be a completely different issue altogether. I mean, if $var3 points to a string, then if I change the string, then `keywords["three"]` should return the new string right?

Comment: @Keikoku If you change the string object itself (via a mutating method called on the string, e.g. `replace` or `gsub!` or `[]=`) then yes; if you are changing the variable to point to a new string (e.g. `$var1 = "bar"`) then no.

Comment: @Phrogz, hmm, I suppose the correct question I should be asking would be "how do I get the value that the variable is currently pointing to". The eval solution up there works of course, but maybe there's a non-eval way to do it?

Comment: Depends on whether you are mutating the string in place (eg using gsub!, strip!, etc) or creating a new string (using the non destructive versions of those methods)

Comment: @Keikoku There is not a non-`eval` way for global or local variables. For instance variables, on the other hand, there is [`instance_variable_get`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html#method-i-instance_variable_get) (link currently broken).